# C++ return an object or change object inside function

Tags: c++, recursion, return-type

I'm new to C++ so am still learning. I am trying to write an algorithm to build a tree recursively, I would usually write it according to Method 1 below, however, as when the function returns it makes a (I hope deep) copy of the RandomTreeNode, I am concerned about calling it recursively and would therefore prefer method 2. Am I correct in my thinking?

**Method 1**

```
RandomTreeNode build_tree(std::vector<T>& data, const std::vector<funcion_ptr>& functions){
        if(data.size() == 0 || data_has_same_values(data)){
            RandomeTreeNode node = RandomTreeNode();
            node.setData(node);
            return node;
        }

        RandomTreeNode parent = RandomTreeNode();
        vector<T> left_data = split_data_left(data);
        vector<T> right_data = split_data_right(data);
        parent.set_left_child(build_tree(left_data));
        parent.set_right_child(build_tree(right_data));
        return parent;
    }
```

**Method 2**

```
void build_tree(RandomTreeNode& current_node, vector<T> data){
    if(data.size() == 0 || data_has_same_values(data)){
        current_node.setData(node);
    }

    vector<T> left_data = split_data_left(data);
    vector<T> right_data = split_data_right(data);

    RandomTreeNode left_child = RandomTreeNode();
    RandomTreeNode right_child = RandomTreeNode();
    current_node.set_left_child(left_child);
    current_node.set_right_child(right_child);

    build_tree(left_child, left_data);
    build_tree(right_child, right_data);

}
```

Comment: Method 1 will likely do what you want, while the tail-recursion in Method 2 will not. The two build_tree calls will be building one-level deep on the local vars left_child and right_child, but those are still local. Copies were sent to set_left_child and set_right_child *before* the recursion. End result for Method 2 will likely be a root node with two empty children.

Comment: continued.. likely there will be a hella-lot of copying going on in Method 1. I suggest the children of a node should instead be smart-pointer-managed dynamic allocations. Lastly, you've quite a lot of redundant constructions.

Comment: @WhozCraig if set_left_child and set_right_child are defined as taking in RandomTreeNode& a copy wont be sent in right? If this is bad practice can you please tell me why? Also, what are the redundant constructions? Sorry for all of the questions but I am quite new to C++

Comment: @WhozCraig however I get that using pointers to the local variables wont work as when the method terminates they no longer exist

Comment: re your first question, correct, if the left and right setters take references as formal parameters copies won't be sent; however, review the code in each of those setters for where the real-copy takes place. your observation of saving pointers to locals is spot-on (correct) and should be avoided. The rest is pretty-much as I said in my initial comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several improvements.

- First, you're copying a vector. As I understand the name of your functions, you're splitting a vector in two blocks (`[left|right]` and not `[l|r|lll|r|...]`). So, instead of passing a vector each time, you can just pass index to specify the ranges.
- The method 2, if well implemented, will be more efficient in memory. So, you should improve the idea behind it.
- Last, you can use an auxilliary function, which will be more suited to the problem (a mix between method 1 and method 2).

Here is some sample code:

```
// first is inclusive
// last is not inclusive
void build_tree_aux(RandomTreeNode& current_node, std::vector<T>& data, int first, int last)
{
    if(last == first || data_has_same_values(data,first,last))
    {
        current_node.setData(data,first,last);
        // ...
    }

    // Find new ranges
    int leftFirst = first;
    int leftLast = split_data(data,first,last);
    int rightFirst = leftLast;
    int rightLast = last;

    // Instead of copying an empty node, we create the children
    // of current_node, and then process these nodes
    current_node.build_left_child();
    current_node.build_right_child();

    // Recursion, left_child() and right_child() returns reference
    build_tree_aux(current_node.left_child(),data,leftFirst,leftLast);
    build_tree_aux(current_node.right_child(),data,rightFirst,rightLast);
    /*
        // left_child() and right_child() are not really breaking encapsulation,
        // because you can consider that the child nodes are not really a part of
        // a node.
        // But if you want, you can do the following:
        current_node.build_tree(data,leftFirst,leftLast);
        // Where RandomTreeNode::build_tree simply call build_tree_aux on the 2 childrens
    */
}

RandomTreeNode build_tree(std::vector<T>& data)
{
    RandomTreeNode root;

    build_tree_aux(root,data,0,data.size());

    return root;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this looks good. However, the split of the vector is not [left|right] its more like [lll|rr|l|r|rr] etc. so I think I'll have to make new smaller vectors?

Comment: Also, does this implementation mean that current_node.left_child() has to return RandomTreeNode& ? Doesn't this break encapsulation?

Comment: First question: If its not `[left|right]`, you will have to create new vectors for each iteration. If you want speed, you can search whether the data can be sorted (or anything else) which could make the data separable in 2 blocks. I can't do this for you, because I don't know which algorithm you're implementing ;). For the last question: see my edit.

Comment: `RandomTreeNode root();` should be `RandomTreeNode root;` to avoid a function-decl error. That aside the use of indexed-based rather than object-consructed-based splitting is a considerable improvement from the OP's original code.